How do I read user input line by line as if it were a file?
I am new to C#. I want to be able to scan a user input line by line in C# (like you can in Java with a scanner or in Go with bufio).
My code needs to handle user input like this:
3
Hans
Grethe
Otto

and output the following:
takk Hans
takk Grethe
takk Otto

my current code
using System;

namespace kattis {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            //number of guests to thank
            string guests = Console.ReadLine();
            //thanking loop
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(guests);i++)
            {
                //read each guests name
                string guest = Console.ReadLine();
                //thank guests
                Console.WriteLine("Takk "+guest);
            }
        }
        
    }
}

I have tried browsing the web and asking my friends who are somewhat familiar with C#. However, I can only figure out how to scan a file line by line and not user input. Also, this is so I can attempt Kattis problems in order to help me learn the language.
I saw something about using other libraries such as barcode, but again I'm new to C# and don't understand everything yet.
I am aware you can use a split method but I fail to recognise how I can use that to my advantage in this case. As far as my understanding go you can't have a string containing multiple lines, you would have to add the new lines yourself.

You can split the line into separate tokens using the String.Split() method. The string class is probably the most useful class for a beginner, so you should study it closely.

Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Thank you for your comments and advice, I will study the string classmore closely. I won't use pictures in the future. I am new to the platform.

May be you want a List<string> which can be used for lines of text. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-8.0

If you want to program in C#, forget about Java and any other computer programming language that you think that you know. Identify the problem that need to be solved, write some pseudo-code, then look use your favorite search engine to find the documentation for what you're trying to achieve. The following may be of interest: Console.Read, iteration statements,

List (List<string> lines = new List<string>();), selection statements, string interpolation, Environment.Newline, and ASCII table.

Here are some more: Int32.TryParse and Environment.Exit.

Another one: In C#, what's the difference between \n and \r\n?

It's worth noting that you haven't said what your current code does compared with what you want it to do. Is the problem just that it's printing out the "thank you" part as it goes, instead of all in one go at the end? (It's not clear why you've mentioned split here, as I don't see any need to split anything...)

Console.ReadLine is what you need almost exactly, it collects user input, until the user hits Enter. So as if the user was feeding line by line. Simple program showing that:
Console.WriteLine("Enter people to give thank to");

var lines = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    lines.Add(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", lines));

But this approach is invalid. Because now we hardcoded that the user will have to enter exactly 10 people always. Not more, not less.
So we have to make it better a little. We need a method that will collect data until the user hits enter, but also allow the user to press, for example, Esc key and quit entering people.
Something like this method (comments in code):
bool ReadLineWithEscape(out string line)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var enteredLine = false;
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        // On enter, we indicate user "wants" to enter new name
        // nad break out of the loop.
        if(key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            enteredLine = true;
            break;
        }
        // On escape, we indictae that user does not want
        // to input anything more.
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            break;

        sb.Append(key.KeyChar);
    }

    line = sb.ToString();
    // Feed the line to enter new person in new line.
    Console.WriteLine();
    return enteredLine;
}

And then you can use it like this:
Console.WriteLine("Enter people to give thank to");

var lines = new List<string>();

while(ReadLineWithEscape(out var line))
{
    lines.Add(line);
}

Console.WriteLine("Entered people:");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", lines));

This, however, would have one bug - when pressing Escape, it consumes next character from console, after it has been read, meaning ntered people: would be displayed (missing first character). But with the help of this SO post, we can easily correct that in our ReadLineWithEscape method:
bool ReadLineWithEscape(out string line)
{
    const bool interceptCharOnReading = true;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var enteredLine = false;
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey(interceptCharOnReading);
        // On escape, we indictae that user does not want
        // to input anything more.
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
        
        // If user did not press Escape, we want to print the character
        if (interceptCharOnReading) Console.Write(key.KeyChar);

        // On enter, we indicate user "wants" to enter new name
        // nad break out of the loop.
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            enteredLine = true;
            break;
        }

        sb.Append(key.KeyChar);
    }

    line = sb.ToString();
    // Feed the line to enter new person in new line.
    Console.WriteLine();
    return enteredLine;
}


"We need a method that will collect data until the user hits enter, but also allow the user to press, for example, Esc key and quit entering people." I think it would be simpler just to say "enter a blank line when you've finished". That ends up with a solution which is much easier to automate and test, IMO. (And still very simple to use.)

Additionally, the question seems to suggest that the required user input already includes the number of names - whereas this answer seems to be primarily around avoiding knowing the number of names before accepting those names.
